# Wordpress load CSS In footer

Tags: wordpress, performance, footer

How can I get this function to load my css in the footer and not in the head for google page speed. I've googled it and tried but I cant seem to get it to work.

```
function broa_script_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style('boostrapcss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', array(), '4.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('animatecss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'broa_script_enqueue' );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `get_footer` hook. Put this code in your active theme's function.php.

```
function prefix_add_footer_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('boostrapcss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', array(), '4.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('animatecss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
};
add_action( 'get_footer', 'prefix_add_footer_styles' );
```

This question is already described here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/186065/how-to-load-css-in-the-footer

Comment: When I do ( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'broa_script_enqueue' ); to add_action( 'wp_footer', 'broa_script_enqueue' );  it wont load the css.

Comment: function prefix_add_footer_styles() But when I do that it wont load my styles for any reason. I tried that one before posting here. I get no php errors or so. But the style wont load.

Comment: With WordPress 6.2, the hook "wp_footer" worked but "get_footer" did not <shrug>. Regardless, your answer helped me so I voted it up.

Answer (score 3):

change add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'broa_script_enqueue' );  to add_action( 'wp_footer', 'broa_script_enqueue' );