# Adding a script to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a simple script that appends a class on scroll depth and would like to use it on my Wordpress site.

How should I go about adding it? I have the class pinpointed and know the CSS side, but I don't know how to get the script to register.

```
The script is:

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 100) {
    $(".header").addClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".header").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress load CSS In footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057380/wordpress-load-css-in-footer)

Answer (score 3):

In your (child) theme's functions.php, add the following lines at the end:

```
function my_enqueue_script()
{
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() .
    '/js/my_custom_script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_script' );
```

with your script inside the theme's subfolder '/js/my_custom_script.js'. Rename my_custom_script.js to anything you like.

Comment: When you enqueue assets like this, it's generally preferable to use [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/). This will cause it to refer to the currently active theme. Using [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) will always refer to the Parent theme (which may or may not be the active theme)